# Thymeleaf: Error resolving template with a jar deployment in a virtual host

Tags: thymeleaf

I'm developing a **Spring Boot application build with Maven**. In my local machine is working, but when I run the .jar in a virtual host for testing purposes, I get this exception:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException:
Error resolving template "/admin/rates/test", template might not exist or might not be 
accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

Those are the configuration elements that I have set for **Thymeleaf**:

In the pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And in the heading of each html page:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

The virtual host is a droplet from Digital Ocean, running on Ubuntu 16.04.2, and with this java version:

```
openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)
```

In my local workstation I have a Windows 10, and I run the application with NetBeans instead of `java -jar MyApplication.jar`, at the Ubuntu terminal.

I may be missing something, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "A virtual host"? What environment is that? What differs from your local machine?

Comment: Thank you  @holmis83, I've added your requested information at the end of the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Had the same issue and i solved it by removing the slash (/) at the begining of the name of the template returned by the controller method. So in your cas i think you should return "admin/rates/test" rather than "/admin/rates/test". And this advice still available for the fragments incusion. for example you should write

```
<th:block th:replace="layout/footer-frag.html::footer"></th:block>
```

rather than

```
<th:block th:replace="/layout/footer-frag.html::footer"></th:block>
```

Comment: This question was made a long time ago, and the solution I found at that time, was this one of your answer.